# Angular @Input() array from other component, problem

Tags: angular, typescript, input, components, display

I am new to Angular, and I am trying to work on a very basic blog application. I have got some help here to retrieve a property from another component via the @Input() decorator, but it doesn't seem to work for arrays, or at least not like that.
In a post-list-item component, embedded in a post-list component, I want to display the values of the properties located in the array of app-component.ts.
Clearly I am missing something, and I don't know what it is, hence asking for your help!

Here is my code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjbppb)

Comment: Something's not fine when you are at post-list.component and then moving to post-list-item.component  For such kind of issues it's always better to replicate the issue on https://stackblitz.com or somewhere. Where it's easier to debug for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the stackblitz. I believe this is the array that you are trying to work through, right?

```
[
  { titrePubli: "Ma première publi", contenuPubli: "C'est le bla bla bla" },
  { titrePubli: "Ma seconde publi", contenuPubli: "Un autre blablabla" },
  { titrePubli: "Ma troisième publi", contenuPubli: "Ohlàlà" },
];
```

You don't have to do it like this:

```
<app-post-list-item
  *ngFor="let p of publisPL"
  [publisIT]="p"
  [titrePubliIT]="p.titrePubliPL"
  [contenuPubliIT]="p.contenuPubliPL"
  [datePubliIT]="p.datePubliPL"
></app-post-list-item>
```

instead you can do something like this:

```
<app-post-list-item
    *ngFor="let p of publisPL"
    [publisIT]="p"
></app-post-list-item>
```

and in post-list-item.component.html you can directly access the values without having all the trouble of having so many methods:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <h3 style="font-size: 20px;">Titre : {{ publisIT?.titrePubli }}</h3>
    <h4 style="font-size: 18px;">Contenu : {{ publisIT?.contenuPubli }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
            (click)="onJadore()">
            J'adore {{ getJadorePubli() }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
            style="position: relative; left: 0.6em;"
            (click)="onJeDeteste()">
            Je déteste {{ getJeDetestePubli() }}</button>
    <p style="display: inline; position: relative; top: 0.6em; left: 1em;">{{ getDatePubli() | date: "EEEE dd/MM/yy HH:mm" }}</p>
</li>
```

Like I have done with the title and content. Currently I only found these two fields in the objects and same would apply to the other fields.

Plus I have made a stackblitz which would make more sense. I removed some of the stuff so you know that what's required and what's not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mini-blog-ex

Comment: Plus if you want to contact me further on this, I can have a zoom session with you but tomorrow. I can help you understand this data sharing stuff quickly.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your answer!! That unlocked a couple things for me. This is quite simpler than I thought, I just have a bit of trouble representing myself the @Input() path across the components. It is a bit tricky to understand, I only need some more practice. I could also manage to get the counters working with onJadorePubli() {{ this.publisIT.jadorePubli++ }}. I understood that @Input() just "renames" (well, decorates!) a field in order to be used in another component, but its values (the ones from the array proprerties here) can be used just like in the source component.

Comment: Not even rename, I normally don't even rename it for consistency. Regarding the counters, can you please further elaborate. For it there can be multiple strategies that can be use. If I know, I would better be able to tell you the right strategy for it.

Comment: Ah right, it doesn't have to "rename" it, but it just seems to import it in order to use it in the component. I'm just trying to understand how this works! As for the counters, let me show you my StackBlitz example, updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjbppb
When you click on the buttons, it increments the numbers next to the text. I have not learned how to store that permanently (in a database or something like that), so it stays simple for now!

Comment: What you have done is not wrong and will work as it will update the model. So when ever you want to send something to the server, you shall easily be able to do it. You can see the stackblitz link that I shared in the answer and you can that through out I have used the same name and one more thing, if you think that this answer works then please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suppouse you want

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of publisPL">
  <app-post-list-item [titrePubliIT]="p.titrePubliPL"
                      [contenuPubliIT]="p.contenuPubliPL"
                      [datePubliIT]="p.datePubliPL"></app-post-list-item>
</ul>
```

or (but change the `@Input()s`

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of publisPL">
  <app-post-list-item [publish]="p">
</ul>

//and use
{{p.titrePubliIT}}
```

And you needn't make functions getTitrePubli(),getContenuPubli(),...

You can use directly

```
{{titrePubliIT}}
```

A `@Input` is also a public variable